# Autocomplete proposal for SWT Combo

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Given the code below, which works correctly, how to implement proposals that *contain* written words, not just proposals that *start with* a given sequence?

I'm looking for something like "% LIKE%" in SQL. For example, writing "car" I want to be proposed words like "verdure carciofi".

```
SimpleContentProposalProvider proposalProviderNegozio = new SimpleContentProposalProvider(combonegozio.getItems());
ContentProposalAdapter proposalAdapterNegozio = new ContentProposalAdapter(combonegozio, new ComboContentAdapter(),
        proposalProviderNegozio, getActivationKeystroke(), getAutoactivationChars());

proposalProviderNegozio.setFiltering(true);
proposalAdapterNegozio.setPropagateKeys(true);
proposalAdapterNegozio.setProposalAcceptanceStyle(ContentProposalAdapter.PROPOSAL_REPLACE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `SimpleContentProposalProvider` write your own class that implements `IContentProposalProvider`.

This interface has only one method:

```java
public IContentProposal[] getProposals(String contents, int position)
```

You are given the current control contents and the insert position and it is up to you to return the appropriate proposals.

You can use the `ContentProposal` class which implements `IContentProposal` for the results.

So a simple provider which returns to proposals if the text is 'car' might be:

```java
class MyProposalProvider implements IContentProposalProvider
{
  @Override
  public IContentProposal [] getProposals(final String contents, final int position)
  {
    if (contents.equals("car")) {
      return new IContentProposal [] {
        new ContentProposal("proposal 1", "description 1", null),  
        new ContentProposal("proposal 2", "description 2", null),  
      };
    }

    return new IContentProposal [0];
  }
}
```

and your code becomes:

```java
IContentProposalProvider myProvider = new MyProposalProvider();
ContentProposalAdapter proposalAdapterNegozio = new ContentProposalAdapter(combonegozio, new ComboContentAdapter(),
        myProvider, getActivationKeystroke(), getAutoactivationChars());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I read the documentation but i didn't realize how to do.can u be more explicit?

Comment: I have added a simple example to the answer, anything more complex is really up to you to code.

Comment: thanks.Who calls getProposals and get IContentProposal Object?

Comment: The ContentProposalAdapter, you replace the SimpleContentProposalProvider in your original code with this new class you create. See updated example.

Comment: ControlProposalAdapter requires  IControlContentAdapter and IContentProposalProvider which etc...it doesn t expect IContenentProposal.Am I lost?

Comment: Your new class (`MyContentProvider` in my example) **is** a `IContentProposalProvider`. That is what the `ContentProposalAdapter` requires for its constructor as shown in the second part of the code. When the content proposal adapter wants proposals it will call the `getProposals` method.

Comment: Forgive me, I've been studying java for 2 weeks, could you kindly write me the complete example so that I can readjust it to my case?I'm not understanding